# post automatically to the Facebook account

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api

I have created a website, in that website I have created one page on which if I write anything I want that to be get posted on my Facebook account, so do you have any API (Application Program Interface) which i can use in my website and through which i can add the post automatically to the Facebook account

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at http://csharpsdk.org/?

It's likely the best resource for you to hook into the Facebook API via .NET framework, specifically the documentation here: http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started